# Mysql Backup of Remote Windows Server through scheduling on Local Machine

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I an having Remote Windows Server having Xampp installed.
And now i want to take backup of Mysql DB every night through scheduled task and to save that backup on my local machine from which i have triggered the scheduled task.
For this, i have created a php script which takes Mysql DB Backup. Also i have created a scheduler that runs the batch file from which i called that php script but the DB Backup file created i been saved on Server only.. 
I have to save it on my local machine...?
Please help to solve this problem..?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Transfer the file from your server to your local machine

Comment: i have to do it through programing & also by task scheduler... then how to transfer the file in this way...?

Answer (score 2):

If you're calling a batch file to execute a PHP file, you could also do the backup directly from that batch file by using mysqldump.exe which is provided by MySQL itself. 
A possible syntax would be:
`"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe" -u%user% -p%pwd% %yourdatabase% > Y:\ourbackuppath\filename.sql`

I hope this is helpful for your purpose.

Comment: yes i tried with mysqldump but i am getting file with 0KB as i am dumping the remote server database, That's why i have gone with the PHP script to execute on task scheduler, as i said earlier. So though looking for an better option..?

Comment: did you try using parameter -f for forcing the output even if you get an SQL error. But run it from command line first to see what errors you get.

Comment: Actually, i tried using this a lot through command prompt but getting error as "mysqldump: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '<remote server ip address>' (0060) when trying to connect"... Any help on this..?

Comment: maybe the user you use to connect to your database has not the privileges to connect from that host. You should see the IP you are allowed to connect from in column `mysql`.`user`.`host`.
Be careful which hosts you allow. You shouldn't use '%'.